# Windows 10 indicates no ethernet cable after upgrade or anniversary update

Tags: ethernet, windows-10-upgrade

After upgrading to Windows 10 or after the Windows 10 Anniversary Update windows tells me that there is no ethernet cable connected even though one is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem when I upgraded to Windows 10 as well as after the Windows 10 Anniversary update. Here is my solution:

1. Open Device Manager and expand "Network adapters"
2. Right click on your Ethernet Controller and select properties.
3. Go into the Advanced Tab.
4. Scroll down to Speed & Duplex and select it.
5. Click the Value dropdown. It's probably set to Auto Negotiation.
6. I used 100 Mbps Full Duplex your Controller may be different.
7. Click OK.

Hope this helps!